# C structs: why does this statement uses . notation to access "swag" and not ->?

Tags: c, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    const char *description;
    float value;
} swag;
typedef struct {
    swag *swag;
    const char *sequence;
} combination;
typedef struct {
    combination numbers;
    const char *make;
} safe;
swag gold = {"GOLD!", 1000000.0};
combination numbers = {&gold, "6502"};
safe s = {numbers, "RAMACON250"};
```

in the above example from a book if we want to get to "GOLD!" stored in the instance of the `swag` type, a book says we need to get to it with `s.numbers.swag->description`.

My question is that since:

1. `s` is an instance of `safe`...
2. ...which has a field `numbers` which in turn is an instance of `combination`...
3. ...which has a field `*swag` that is a pointer by itself...
4. ...and we want to access the string `description` within it

shouldn't we write `s.numbers->swag->description` as in why `...numbers.swag...` and not `...numbers->swag...`

Comment: if pointer use (`->`) if not use (`.`), to answer your question is `numbers` a pointer?

Comment: @kiranBiradar So, you are saying "because `*swag` is a field in `numbers` which is not a pointer, we need to use `. `and not `->` to access `*swag`?" Did I understand correctly?

Comment: The "arrow" operator `->` combines pointer dereference and member access. In your example `s.numbers.swag->description` it's equivalent to `(*(s.numbers.swag)).description`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I hear you, but did I understand what kiranBiradar said correctly? I understand what you are explaining. Am currently kind of thrown off by the chaining.

Comment: `s` is not a pointer, therefore you access its members using `.`. Then `s.numbers` is not a pointer either, therefore you access its members using `.`. Then `s.numbers.swag` *is* a pointer, therefore you access its members using `->`. Leading to the final `s.numbers.swag->description` expression.

Comment: What Kiran means is: `numbers` is no pointer. Therefore no `->swag` but `.swag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get to the member of `swag` you have to dereference it, because it is a pointer and you have to get to that object pointed to first.

So if `swag` is a pointer and you want to get its member `description`, you have to do something like this `(*swag).description`, meaning "get to the pointed to object" `*swag`, and get its member `.description`.

C (and C++) provide a short form for `(*x).y`, which is `x->y`.
`->` combines dereferencing (`*x`) and accessing (`.`)

So because `numbers` isn't a pointer and you don't need to dereference it first, you can access its member `swag` just with a `.`, but to access a member of `swag` you need to use `->`, because `swag` is a pointer.